# About Whitehead's problem

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, independence-results

Hi I am new to proofs of consistency and independence with ZFC of some claims. I have read "The uses of set theory" by Judith Roitman, in that article it is mentioned that the Whitehead conjecture ($\mathsf{WC}$) is independent of ZFC. In fact, it is mentioned that $\mathsf{MA} + \neg \mathsf{CH}$ implies $\mathsf{WC}$ and Jensen's diamond principle implies $\neg\mathsf{WC}$. Does anyone have a bibliography on the proofs of these facts? Taking advantage of the opportunity, someone knows more results of independent or consistent results with ZFC, demonstrated in a similar way (for example, "every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with cardinality $\aleph_1$ has measure zero" is independent of ZFC, to prove this fact Martin's axiom shows that statement and CH shows the negation).

Thanks

Comment: A very good reference is                                                       [Whitehead's Problem is Undecidable](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2318684?seq=1). For more results in this direction, you may look at the book [Almost Free Modules: Set-theoretic Methods](https://www.elsevier.com/books/almost-free-modules/eklof/978-0-444-50492-0).

Comment: The book                                                                         [Consequences of Martin's Axiom](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/consequences-of-martins-axiom/95D39CA5BC839C5E93EB202C5D32ADEF) contains a lot of consequences of MA

Comment: Thanks for the information Professor Mohammad.

Comment: just Mohammad is sufficient!

Comment: Nik Weaver's book "forcing for mathematicians" has two whole chapters on Whitehead's problem, together with all the background on forcing and other machinery that is needed. I haven't read those two chapters myself, but I used other parts of the books and they were very well written.

Comment: Thanks for the information professor Alessandro